# htaccess ReWrite for images

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this code in my .htaccess file which redirects all web pages inside the `main_website` folder but currently images are stored in the root

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(blog)/(post|tags|category)/([\w-]+)/?$ main_website/index.php?id=$1&type=$2&unique=$3 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(blog)/(archives)/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})?$ main_website/index.php?id=$1&type=$2&year=$3&month=$4 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(support/knowledgebase)/(article|category|search)/([\w-]+)/?([0-9]+)?$ main_website/index.php?id=$1&type=$2&unique=$3&pagenum=$4 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(account/hosting)/([\w-]+)?$ main_website/index.php?id=$1&p=$2 [QSA,NC,L]

# This will process the /section/(.*) requests, ?section=1 will be appended to query string    
RewriteRule ^section\/(.*)?$ main_website/index.php?section=1&id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^/?$ main_website/index.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/_]+)/?$ main_website/index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

How can i alter the above to move my `images` folder to the `main_website` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `images` folder under `main_website/` and then you can use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?$ main_website/index.php [L]

# redirect images to main_website/images/
RewriteRule ^images/.+$ /main_website/$0 [L,NC,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(blog)/(post|tags|category)/([\w-]+)/?$ main_website/index.php?id=$1&type=$2&unique=$3 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(blog)/(archives)/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})?$ main_website/index.php?id=$1&type=$2&year=$3&month=$4 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(support/knowledgebase)/(article|category|search)/([\w-]+)/?([0-9]+)?$ main_website/index.php?id=$1&type=$2&unique=$3&pagenum=$4 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(account/hosting)/([\w-]+)?$ main_website/index.php?id=$1&p=$2 [QSA,NC,L]

# This will process the /section/(.*) requests, ?section=1 will be appended to query string    
RewriteRule ^section\/(.*)?$ main_website/index.php?section=1&id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w/-]+)/?$ main_website/index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: im getting a Forbidden message on the pages

Comment: Just the main domain with a / at the end, no other path